# Ajax call to a PHP page always returns nothing even though the PHP page echoes something

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am calling a very simple PHP page with some equally simple AJAX, but the call always returns nothing, even though the PHP is fine. That is, you can go to the URL of the PHP page and see that it echoes "Hello World" but when it is called with JS, it returns nothing.

**Below is the HTML Page with the Javascript:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......<br />

Enter your email: <input id="email" type="text" />
<input type="button" onclick="setXMLHttpRequest()" value="Go!" />

<script type='text/javascript'/>

        var http;

        function setXMLHttpRequest()
        {
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
                http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            else if(window.ActiveXObject)
                http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

                url = "http://www.convolutedconstruct.com /Ajax/checkemail.php?email=" + 
                                   document.getElementById('email').value;
                http.onreadystatechange = display;
                http.open("GET", url, true);
                http.send(null);

        }

        function display()
        {
            if (http.readyState == 4)
            {   
                infostr = http.responseText;
                alert("From the PHP: " + infostr);
            }
        }
</script></body></html>
```

Here is the content of the PHP page
[Click here for the live PHP page](http://convolutedconstruct.com/Ajax/checkemail.php)

```
<?php
$email = $_GET['email'];
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

Why does this return nothing to the JS, even though the PHP page echoes the text correctly?

Comment: Let me guess, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @adnan said this ain't a valid path for AJAX: `convolutedconstruct.com/Ajax/checkemail.php?email=` if you want cross origin try JSONP

Comment: Or rather just make you path: `/Ajax/checkemail.php?email=`

Comment: Oops! I'll change that to HTTP.

Comment: Still not right..."cross origin", normal AJAX does not accept domain names in it's path.

Comment: Okay I've tried with "http://" and "http://www." but neither of them worked. Darn I thought that was my mistake.

Comment: Can you update the question with the URL you are now using.

Comment: @Sammaye, you're wrong. You **can** use domain names in the requested URL, that's not the issue. Both of you please read the Wiki I linked to. If learn it by yourself, you'll never forget it.

Comment: @Jamil, where are you placing your HTML file? the one with the Javascript that's making the Ajax request.

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'/> is the fact that this is closed a typo in the SO post, or your actual code?

Comment: @Adnan Not in the same directory as the PHP file. I will do that now and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been suggested above, AJAX request will only work usually when both the caller and called are on same domain, You have to ensure that your html code, which contains the javascript, resides on same domain http://www.convolutedconstruct.com.

If that is not the case you can use CORS to allow your ajax to receive input from your php page by sending this header in your php output

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
//rest of your code
?>
```

See: http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: I will put both pages in the same directory on the server. In that case should I use a relative path or stick with the http prefix?

Comment: They don't necessarily need to be in same dir, but if that helps you for convenience then yes it's good. You can use relative path or absolute path that also would not break the ajax request as long as the domain and the scheme are same. So if your page resides on http://www.example.com  then it should be able to receive data from any page on http://www.example.com. I use full path generally

Answer (score 1):

i dont like using the XMLHTTP request. instead i use jQuery's method `$.ajax({});` method. it always works for me!

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", // or 'GET'
    url: "your-url.php", // url that you are passing the data to
    data: {
        dataName: 'data to pass' // string, variable, object, array, etc
    },
    success: function(output) { // output is what the url is 'echoing' back to the jQuery
        // do something when the ajax method is complete.
    }
});
```

**dont forget to import the jQuery source code** - http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js

these are the most common of the components that are used in ajax.

I'll be glad to help you out some more if you would like it.

If you want to know more just check the documentation on it: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/